# MS Access: Rank/Priority Sorting

Tags: ms-access

I'm at a total loss at how to accomplish the following scenario in Access:

Say I have two tables, Users and Tasks.

```
Users                        Tasks
----------------------        ----------------------
Username [Primary Key] <1--∞> Username [Foreign Key]
                              Task ID [Primary Key]
                              Priority
```

I'd like to display a form that shows a particular user's tasks, sorted by Priority (an integer). The priority is not fixed, and I need to make sure no two tasks from the same user have the same priority. I have no clue how to accomplish this using Access. What kind of query do I need to build for the form? Ideally, I'd like to have two buttons on the form to raise/lower the Task's Priority.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm not averse to using VBA if that's what it takes, but I have a feeling there's an elegant solution to this.

(Note: the actual DB I'm working on is very different, but knowing how to do this will allow me to figure out how to get what I need.)

Answer (score 1):

A unique index on Username and Priority on the Tasks table will enforce your rule. A warning will be given when the user attempts to save data that violates this key. You may want to trap the error and provide a little better explanation.

The main form can be based on the Users and a subform based on Tasks. Access will aid in helping you use the UserName (your key fields) for the Parent Form and Child Form.

A little VBA on the current record can increment the Priority field. You would have two buttons each with their on On_Click event to increase/decrease the value. Example:  `[Priority] = [Priority] + 1`

Comment: That helps. Say I want to swap priorities when I incrment/decrement the value. How would that work?

Comment: @user1082589 You can use recordsets to select matching priorities in the before update event and check with the user for the action required. Before update allows the event to be cancelled for this record priority, or you can  update the matching priority to a pre-tested value.

Comment: Excellent. Last question now... how do I pre-fill the Priority field to be equal to the number of existing Tasks for the User?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the current record's Username, TaskID and Priority you need to run three queries:

- First park the priority of the current record, set it to null or zero or some other value for a moving record.
- Then make the space by changing the record thats in the way.
- Finally move the parked record into it's new slot.

To move the current record up run each of these in VBA:

```
"UPDATE Tasks SET Priority = 0 WHERE Username='" & MyUsername & "' AND [Task ID]=" & MyTaskID

"UPDATE Tasks SET Priority = " & MyPriority - 1  & " WHERE Username='" & MyUsername & "' AND Priority=" & MyPriority + 1

"UPDATE Tasks SET Priority = " & MyPriority + 1  & " WHERE Username='" & MyUsername & "' AND Priority = 0"
```

Swap the +1 and -1 s to go the other way.

You can do it with two queries if you don't have a unique index on unername/priority, but I suggest that you add one. You can also wrap them in a transaction for some safety in a multi user environment.